# React and IPFS - Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: PubsubRouter is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, js-ipfs

I am trying to fetch some json data on IPFS but keep getting hit by this error in the console on page load (and on click).

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: PubsubRouter is not a constructor: pubsub-adapter.js:17

Heres my basic *App.tsx*:

```js
import { ipfsFetch } from "ipfs-fetch"
import React, { useState } from "react"
import "./App.css"

function App() {
    const [tokenId, setTokenId] = useState()

    const fetchOnIpfs = async (tokenId: number) => {
        return await ipfsFetch(`<cid>/${tokenId}.json`)
    }

    return (
        <div className='App'>
            <input onChange={e => setTokenId(e.target.value)} />
            <button onClick={() => fetchOnIpfs(tokenId)}>TEST</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

I am using the `ipfs-fetch` package uses the `ipfs-core` under the hood. I've tried using `ipfs-core` directly and other package ipfs packages which all give the same error.

On the other hand, this works fine:

```js
const { ipfsFetch } = require("ipfs-fetch")

const main = async () => {
    const res = await ipfsFetch("<cid>/1.json")
    console.log(res.toString())
}

main()
```

Which leads me to believe that the problem has to do with react. What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to do this in react?

Comment: What about the  pubsub-adapter.js file ? Is this from your source ? or a lib that you call somewhere ?

Comment: It's part of the ipfs library

Comment: Have you checked if the value in `tokenId` is valid before using it for the request ?

Comment: Yeah I've checked with a valid hardcoded cid and the problem occurs regardless.

Comment: The error seems to be from this file https://github.com/andreaabellera/LibP2P-Playground/blob/bd6d98d64472c6858f75e8871686a524a0ffbfed/src/pubsub-adapter.js#L17 which is not part of the ipfs lib. Do you use this in your dependencies ?

Comment: I just started getting the same issue today as well.

Comment: @Peterrabbit I am using `ipfs-fetch` package which uses `ipfs-core` and uses that somewhere to create a 'repo' (image: https://ibb.co/S05t6rw). This is the `ipfs-fetch` package in question: https://github.com/cyph/ipfs-fetch/blob/master/index.js#L10

Comment: Ok then, maybe this is just an issue that could be addressed to the libp2p maintainer.. Anyway, this definitely does'nt look like a React issue.